# Classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

I am defining a class in JavaScript

```
function Pen(parent){
    this.color = "#0000ff";
    this.stroke = 3;
    this.oldPt;
    this.oldMidPt;
    this.isActive = false;
    this.parent = parent; //app that owns this pen
    this.points = [];
    this.curShape;
        console.log(this);
    return(this);
}
```

In the console.log statement I am getting *way* more than just this class, I am getting all kinds of information about basically everything else going on. Why is that?

Comment: [Google is your friend](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)... `var pen = new Pen();`

Comment: If you call your constructor 'Pen' without the `new` keyword `this` refers to the global Object (`window` probably) thus you see all `window`'s properties

Comment: Thanks guys, I can't believe I spent the amount of time looking at this thing without noticing that I omitted new!

Comment: just use this library http://classjs.weew.ch/, it does all the tricky stuff for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the keyword `this` is dependent on the caller, so if you are initializing the function without the "new" keyword "this" might very well be referencing the window and not the object.

Try:

```
function Pen(parent){
    var context = this;
    this.color = "#0000ff";
    this.stroke = 3;
    this.oldPt;
    this.oldMidPt;
    this.isActive = false;
    this.parent = parent; //app that owns this pen
    this.points = [];
    this.curShape;
        console.log(context);
    return(this);
}
 var pen = new Pen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your "class" inherits (transparently, in your case) from other javascript base classes. If you want to introspect only the properties you've created on your object, use `hasOwnProperty(keyName)` to filter those out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Javascript is prototype based and not class based. Every new custom object as default
has pre built functionlity provided by the base object called Object.
So everytime you ask if a property or method belongs to a given object, in the worst
case it will fall until the Object object, and if that property/method is not there
then it will throw an error. Therefore when you are using the log function it is
printing all the object structure including properties and method of its "base" class.
```